# GNU Make and Windows Powershell : "Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore" does not work

Tags: powershell, makefile, error-handling, gnu-make

I am converting a Makefile (working in linux bash) to run it in a Windows PowerShell Console. I use GNU Make 4.2.1. I have a problem to transform rm bash command to the PowerShell equivalent
For example, in this simple makefile

`clean:
    powershell " Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore aaa.txt"
    powershell " Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore bbb.txt"`

if aaa.txt does not exist, an error is raised even with the `ErrorAction` flag `Ignore` and obviously, the second action (removing of bbb.txt) is not executed. The following message is printed *make: *** [makefile:2: clean] Error 1*.

**Why it does not work ?** (I read that Ignore doesn't add the error message to the $Error automatic variable)

**Which option must I use in the Remove-Item command ?**

For information, if I run the following ***mybat.bat*** file, it works perfectly, even if aaa.txt file does not exist, the bbb.txt file is removed.

```
powershell " Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore aaa.txt"
powershell " Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore bbb.txt"
```

Rq : `powershell " Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore aaa.txt, bbb.txt"` works in this simple case but it is not a good solution because I use makefile that calls many makefile in different directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MadScientist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55461026/45375) provides helpful background information and a pragmatic workaround that is *external* to PowerShell.

As for **why PowerShell reported exit code `1`**:

- When using the CLI with the (implied) `-Command` parameter, it is the (last) statement's success status, as reflected in the Boolean automatic variable `$?`, that is mapped onto exit codes `0` (`$true`) and `1` (`$false`).
- The intentionally *silent* failure of `Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore aaa.txt`  is surprisingly reflected in `$?` as `$false` nonetheless, resulting in exit code `1`.

  - This surprising behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4613).

**Workaround** (if the problem needs to be resolved from within PowerShell):

In the simplest case, append `; $null` (escaped as `; $null` for use in a Makefile):

```
clean:
    powershell "Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore aaa.txt; $$null"
    powershell "Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore bbb.txt; $$null"
```

Outputting `$null` via the CLI is quiet, successful no-op that resets the exit code to `0`.

Another option - available up to v6.x only - is to enclose a command in parentheses:

```
clean:
    powershell "(Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore aaa.txt)"
    powershell "(Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore bbb.txt)"
```

`(...)` turns a command into an expression, and this expression is considered successful in itself, even if the enclosed command reports a (non-terminating) error, which resets `$?` to `$true` and therefore results in exit code `0`.
Note that this behavior is surprising too, as discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3359), which is why it was changed in v7.0, to better support `&&` and `||`, the [pipeline-chain operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about PowerShell, but make doesn't care about what text is printed by the commands that are invoked.  It *only* cares about the exit code.

Based on your experience it appears that PowerShell `Remove-Item` still exits with a non-0 (failure) exit code if the file doesn't exist and the `Ignore` action just tells it to not print the error.

Note that your batch file is not what make does.  It does something more like:

```
powershell " Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore aaa.txt"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 <fail>
```

If you want make to ignore errors and continue anyway you can use [the `-` prefix](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html) for the recipe line:

```
clean:
        -powershell " Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore aaa.txt"
        powershell " Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore bbb.txt"
```