# make/Makefile error: fails executing Remove-Item on PowerShell, Windows even with -ErrorAction Ignore

Tags: windows, powershell, makefile

I posted this problem because I had trouble finding anything about it online. I'm on Windows 10 and I'm new to `make`. Using `make` to run `Remove-Item` on PowerShell (both on a normal terminal and Visual Studio's Developer PowerShell console) fails to ignore errors, basically non-existent files to be removed.

Here is the portion of my Makefile concerned and that doesn't run:

```
REMOVE_COMMAND = Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore

clean:
    $(REMOVE_COMMAND) *.o
```

Here is the error when running `make clean`:

```
Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore *.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore *.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:4: clean] Error 2
```

How can I make `make` run `Remove-Item` to delete files and ignore non-existent ones?

What's weird is that running `Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore *.o` as a standalone command on PowerShell runs fine (even without `-ErrorAction Ignore`). I don't believe that the text substitution has anything to do that causes the error since I've tried running `make` both substituting the command and not. I'm substituting the command because I will be running this Makefile on Linux as well (and so will use `rm` for that case instead).

Comment: make is not invoking powershell.  It's invoking `cmd.exe`.  If you want it to run powershell instead, you have to set the `SHELL` makefile variable to the powershell executable.

Comment: @MadScientist I applied your suggestion and now it works fine. Precisely, I prepended `SHELL = C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. However, on my actual file, successive `Remove-Item` commands of identical form were performed and before the third `Remove-Item` ran, `make` spat out `make: *** [Makefile:56: clean] Error 1` without further explanation. But, it's not a concern for now and I will post a new problem if needed. Thank you.

Edit: I figured that it was Visual Studio's fault as those files attempted to be removed were being used somehow. Exited and now it works

Answer (score 1):

#### Returning PowerShell Codes For One Liners As Expected

I have seen some Stack Exchange posts where you can end your PowerShell Make Recipe with **$$null**:

```
    clean:
        Remove-Item -Path <NONEXISTENT_PATH>; $$null;
```

(e.g [GNU Make and Windows Powershell : "Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore" does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459737/gnu-make-and-windows-powershell-remove-item-erroraction-ignore-does-not-wor)).

But sometimes you may want your Make Recipe to have knowledge of the exit codes. After instructing Make which shell to use (see below), simply wrap your command with:

```
    & { exit $$( <POSH_COMMAND> ) }
```

You will be able to pass exit codes to Make. I know some experts may have issues with this but it works for one liners.

##### Tell Make Your Shell

```
    ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
        SHELL := pwsh.exe
        .SHELLFLAGS := -NoProfile -Command 
    endif
```

If you are just using PowerShell, then you don't need the conditional.

##### Create Your Target

I am showing three frequent ErrorActions and there resultant Make outcomes.

1. ErrorAction Stop

```
    clean:
        & {exit $$(Remove-Item -Path <NONEXISTENT_PATH> -ErrorAction Stop);}
```

Recipe Output:

```
    Remove-Item: Cannot find path <NONEXISTENT_PATH> because it does not exist.<br>
    make: *** [Makefile:<line>: clean] Error 1
```

2. ErrorAction Continue

```
    clean:
        & { exit $$(Remove-Item -Path <NONEXISTENT_PATH> -ErrorAction Continue); }
```

Recipe Output:

```
    Remove-Item: Cannot find path <NONEXISTENT_PATH> because it does not exist.
```

3. ErrorAction Continue

```
    clean:
        & { exit $$(Remove-Item -Path <NONEXISTENT_PATH> -ErrorAction Ignore); }
```

Has no recipe output. This is as is expected.